# Create polygon after excluding extents from raster data having no-data values

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, rasterio

I want to get extent of raster dataset after excluding the extents containing no-data values in the raster data which I then want to export as a shapefile. Till now I have used the following code:

```
import rasterio

with rasterio.open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\PRODUCT1\Landsat\T1.tif') as src:
    bounds = src.bounds
    
from shapely.geometry import box
geom = box(*bounds)

import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id":1,"geometry":[geom]})
df.crs = src.crs
df.to_file(r"C:\Users\Desktop\PRODUCT1\Landsat\T1_boundary.shp")
```

After running the above code I am getting raster extents containing no-data values.

Can someone please help me out in getting the raster extents excluding the extents having no-data values.

Comment: @BERA. The no-data values are surrounding my Image data pixels.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a polygon of the actual valid data, you can use [`rasterio.features.shapes()`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.shapes) to polygonize a boolean mask of your data as the source, e.g. `(data !== src.nodata).astype(np.uint8)`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

import rasterio
from rasterio import features
from shapely.geometry import shape


path = '/vsicurl/http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/usgs/m30dem.tif'

with rasterio.open(path) as f:
    image = f.read(1)
    # use f.nodata if possible; it's not defined on this particular image
    nodata = -32768
    # create a binary image, 0 where there's nodata, 1 where it's valid
    is_valid = (image != nodata).astype(np.uint8)
    # vectorize the binary image, supplying the transform so it returns maps coords
    for coords, value in features.shapes(is_valid, transform=f.transform):
        # ignore polygons corresponding to nodata
        if value != 0:
            # convert geojson to shapely geometry
            geom = shape(coords)
            print(geom)
```

If you're truly looking for the extent of valid data, create that same array, feed it into `np.where()` to get array indices/image coordinates where valid data exists, take the min/max of the axes, and use the [`src.transform.xy()`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.xy) method to convert back to map coords

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Inside "with rasterio.open('....')", I had used following commands: "    image = src.read(1) " & then "image = (image != src.nodata).astype(np.uint8)". Post this when I am using "plt.imshow(image)" then the plot contains the whole image including "No Data" region.

Comment: @RRSCNGP you should be looking at a binary mask which you can then polygonize.  I've added a full example

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me. Thanks for the help.